# JS callback error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Tags: javascript, callback

I am learning JS and read that functions can be passed around as parameters just any other variable. In the following code, when I pass anonymous function as parameter it gives `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function"`

```
var x;
function myfun(x, function(x) { 
   console.log("Value of x is: "+ x );
});

myfun(2,4);
```

I am more interested in knowing the logic behind the error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
bt

Comment: Function parameters should follow the same syntax as variable names. Also where is the function's body?

Comment: You have it backwards. The anonymous function needs to go inside your myfun() call, as 2nd argument. The definition needs to be: `function myfun(x, f) { f(x); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you seem to attempt to declare two functions, one named `myfun`, which takes two arguments, and one unnamed (anonymous) function, which takes one argument. There appears to be two syntax errors in your code: (1) The function `myfun` does not have a function body, and (2) that you declare a function in the argument list of `myfun`.

Let us approach this by declaring both functions first (giving the second one a name and giving `myfun` a function body):

```
function myfun(x, functionToBeCalled) {
  functionToBeCalled(x);
}

function functionToBePassed(x) { 
   console.log("Value of x is: "+ x );
}
```

Now, we can call the function `myfun` and pass it two arguments, a value for `x` and a function to be called within `myfun`—the function `functionToBePassed`:

```
myfun(2, functionToBePassed);
```

If you want the second function to be passed anonymously, declare this function when you *call* the function `myfun`, not when you *declare* `myfun`:

```js
//declare myfun
function myfun(x, functionToBeCalled) {
  functionToBeCalled(x);
}

//call myfun and pass a function as an argument
myfun(2, function(x) { 
  console.log("Value of x is: "+ x );
});
```

Comment: [quote]If you want the second function to be passed anonymously, declare this function when you call the function myfun, not when you declare myfun: [/quote]                                               This was exactly what I wanted to do but got confused just reading and reading. Just this statement, put many concepts in prespective. Awesome answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a anonymous function as parameter you must at least specify its parameter name. So, when this parameter is **`undefined`**, it is assigned with this function, but we can't confirm we'll receive a function, so it's better to make a condition instead.

Example – setting default value of `fnc` parameter. This is a new browser implementation.

```
function myfun(x, fnc = function(x) {
    console.log("Value of x is: " + x)
})

{
    /* block statement is always required in a function declaration */
    fnc(x)
}
```

Example – checking if `b` is a function

```
function myfun(x, fnc)

{
    typeof fnc !== 'function' && (fnc = function(x) {
        console.log("Value of x is: " + x)
    })
    fnc(x)
}
```

But what you wanted to do is:

```
function myfun(x) {
    console.log("Value of x is: " + x)
}
```

You just need to directly declare the block statement using **`{...}`**.